# Diesel intake heater DIY

Tags: diesel, air-intake, heat, block-heater

I am the owner of an older 3.0 liter diesel car and winter mornings are quite painful for both me and the car. Even though thermostat is fine, heating takes forever. I know diesel only heats up while driving, but since  my daily route is very short, I arrive at work with the temperature gauge still in the blue area, even though I let it run for 5-10 minutes before taking off. While this is very bad to the engine, it's also very uncomfortable for the passengers.
I am thinking of building an intake air heater to run it for a few minutes after starting the car, an arduino controlled DIY with a few cheap chinese heating elements and a build solid and responsible enough to avoid setting the car on fire obviously.

I'm ok with waiting 5 minutes for the car to heat up, as long as it does heat and defrost in this period.

Are there any drawbacks to this approach? I don't see this being a common thing anywhere. Will it confuse the ECU, because the external temperature sensor will read like -10 while the intake will read +30?
is there anything else to take into account before starting this build?

Comment: What will be the total power (in Watts) of the heaters that you are planning to use?

Comment: I'm planning to stay in the 200-300w range to avoid putting load on the alternator and draw the battery. I'll perform some measurements once my heating elements arrive. I ordered this https://s.click.aliexpress.com/e/bHCZ6b1O and it gets burning hot in seconds. Six of these will be below 200w so it should be fine

Comment: I would be very surprised if 300w warmed your car significantly.  Have you looked into purchasing a diesel burning heater as fitted to some luxury cars - https://www.webasto-comfort.com/en-uk/heating/ These give heat output in kWs.

Comment: As I said I'm not looking to heat the car itself, but increase the combustion temperature, which will heat the car faster than it currently does. My car had a stock webasto which of course doesn't work even though I've spent a lot of time fixing it

Comment: I have just read your text again and it isn't clear that you are asking to heat the air going into the engine.

Comment: Have you done some research that shows that warming the air will increase the combustion temperature?  I would have thought you would be better heating the engine coolant.

Comment: I would put a small heater (300 to 400W) under the bonnet and heat the engine for a few hours before use. I do this where I am and it makes the car **so** much easier to start - less stress on just about everything... But you will need access to power and a timer...

Comment: warming the air will indeed increase the temperature, I just want to know how much of a difference it will make (if you google "diesel air intake heater" you'll see it is a thing). I've evaluated all other solutions like grid power heating, stock webasto, third party "chinese webasto", heat accumulators and others and I think the best one for me is a bolt-on intake air heater because I'm ok with waiting 5 minutes (might as well add remote start), it is simple, cheap and easy to revert

Comment: You say it's an older diesel, has it always been like this, or is it more recent?

Comment: Diesel air intake heaters are for improving starting of the engine, just like glow plugs.  They are not for increasing the combustion temperature.  I don't see how they will get the engine up to temperature any quicker.

Comment: it was acceptable as long as the webasto was operational, now it's painfully slow. it's a 2002 bmw 530d so the engine is pretty modern, it has most of the features modern diesels have, except the newer emission blockers like dpf or adblue. another issue with these engines is they are using a viscous clutch fan, which spins all the time (slower when cold though) and moves the cold air around which makes heating even slower

Comment: in fact you just gave me an idea, I'll use a blow hair dryer on it's lowest power setting for a test, just to measure the difference it makes. this should be enough to prove a point

Comment: Have you checked that the coolant thermostat is working correctly?

Comment: "Even though thermostat is fine.." do you even read? :)

Comment: OK missed that, probably because I initially thought you were talking about heating the interior.  Can't say I like your attitude to someone trying to help - "do you even read?".

Comment: Was just trying to be sarcastic in a funny way, never meant to offend. Sorry if I did